# Insert the parent Id on each row of a collection FormType

Tags: symfony

I'm working on Symfony 3.4
I wanna embed a collection of form in the parent form. Everything is going well. When I persist, it's only the first row of my collection which can have the form's Parent Id, the others are null.
I'v thy the foreach, but isn't working. May u help me on that point ...

Thanks !!!

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $professeur = new Professeur();
    $eleve      = new Eleve();
    $eleve->setProfesseur($professeur);
    $professeur->addElefe($eleve);
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ProfesseurType', $professeur);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($professeur);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('professeur_show', ['id' => $professeur->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('professeur/new.html.twig', [
        'professeur' => $professeur,
        'form'       => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: please show the AppBundle\Form\ProfesseurType as well

Answer (score 0):

ok

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nom')
            ->add('prenom')
            ->add('note')
            ->add('eleves', CollectionType::class,[
                    'entry_type' => EleveType::class,
                    'allow_add'    => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                ]

                )
    ;
}
```